# How to pass integer array list containing drawable images from activity to activity through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How to pass integer array list containing drawable images from activity to activity through intent same as arraylist

```
 int[] imageId = {R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image,R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image};
```

Comment: Just `intent.putExtra("images", imageId)`

Answer (score 0):

**current Activity**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(current.this, New.class);
myIntent.putExtra("images", imageId);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**New.class**

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();         
 if(b!=null)
 {
 ArrayList<Integer> arr = (ArrayList<Integer>)b.getIntegerArrayListExtra("images");

 }
```